# Fighting Rage Downvotes

Tags: discussion, reputation, down-votes

I just posted some feedback on a question about how it could be better, and about how it is too open ended (I've done this on a few questions now). Within a minute, 5 of my older, accepted, upvoted questions got -1s, all at the same time. It seems to me like someone disliked what I said and went on a downvote spree on my questions.

The rep loss wasn't really substantial, 4,  however it actually knocked me down a rank, causing me to lose the privilege to be able to edit tags. Furthermore, the older questions that were valid and helpful to the community now have less upvotes.

How do we deal with rage downvotes? Is there anything in place for this? The person probably doesn't care about the mutual rep loss penalty for them.

Comment: You sit and wait until the serial voting script runs.

Comment: Ha! @Mysticial - specifically from that first question: "Please do not try to get help on this issue on meta or by flagging for a moderator. All they will do is tell you to wait for the voting fraud script to run (they won't run it just for you just this once)." - LOL

Comment: Well, in cases where it's more than 'a few' votes, e.g. someone is serially raging through your history - yes, that deserves a flag to alert the moderators. When it's just a few votes, just shrug it off, the system will reverse most instances of this automatically.

Comment: @TimPost this is a good 5 downvotes

Comment: @TimPost Wouldn't it be the other way around? The *more* votes it is, the more likely it will be reverted. If it's just 3 votes, I doubt that will get reverted. Since there's been targeted cases where somebody cast 3 a day for a quite a while before finally getting caught.

Comment: @Mysticial When it's _that_ egregious, someone probably needs to be contacted privately, which is why flagging makes sense in those cases.

Comment: @TimPost Ah, ic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't worry. It is called *serial downvoting* and will be detected by the system automatically.

Wait a day to give the batch time to run. If not reversed (some serial downvoters try to fly under the radar), flag one of your downvoted posts for moderator attention and explain your concern.

Comment: Great that they have a system for this. Sorry for the duplicate guys!

Comment: Wow, i did not know that SO did implement a solution for that one, nice work..

Comment: This is awesome. I just got downvoted on 10+ questions by someone who didn't like my suggestion.